# How to say "The last time when..."

Tags: translation, conjunction, time, relative-clause

I want to say

> The last time, when I ate in a restaurant, ...

Should I use "als"? I can't seem to find any examples of it on the internet, nor any explanation of using when in a relative clause.

Comment: [Reference 1](https://courses.dcs.wisc.edu/wp/readinggerman/als-wenn-wann/) [Reference 2](https://www.thegermanprofessor.com/als-wenn-wann/)

Comment: The danger connected to asking with snippets only is, that the translation may not fit into the full context you intend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I as a native German would say:

> Das letze Mal, als ich in einem Restaurant gegessen habe,...

It would also be possible to say:

> Das letzte Mal, dass ich in einem Restaurant gegessen habe,...

But it would mean more like

> The last time, that I ate in a restaurant, ...

And in the common sense of language, "als" is definitely preferred.

Comment: ich glaube diese Übersetzung ist falsch "The last time, that I ate restaurant," I ate in a  restaurant?

Comment: Beides ist möglich. In diesem Falle ist `that` [optional](https://www.cambridge.org/grammarandbeyond/grammar-practice-activities/2016/05/where-did-that-go-omitting-relative-pronouns)

Comment: Yes, there was a typo. Corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use also use "dass". Canonically, however, "als" ist recommended. Sporadically you also find "da" as in "Das letzte Mal, da Ich im Abendmahl—Saal umgeben von Meinen Aposteln der Zweiten Zeit das Abendmahl einnahm". https://books.google.de/books?id=KBWTprBHtlIC&pg=PA38&lpg=PA38&dq=%22das+letzte+mal+da+ich+im%22&source=bl&ots=5dgeOTqEmP&sig=ACfU3U3EflWE9h-G8Z2DgBRNOqH7CZqFXQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiPy-2cqrjnAhWN6qQKHYDJCfgQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22das%20letzte%20mal%20da%20ich%20im%22&f=false   This use has a slightly archaic flavour though.

Comment: So "Das letztes Mal, dass ich in einem Restaurant gegessen habe, ..."?

Comment: Yes, you can use that.

Comment: "Das letzte Mal, dass ich in einem Restaurant gegessen habe" ist aber etwas völlig anderes als "Das letzte Mal, als ich in einem Restaurant gegessen habe". Im ersten Fall werde ich es voraussichtlich nie wieder tun, im zweiten Fall beschreibe ich einen Zeitpunkt.

Comment: "Dass" und "als" haben verschiedene Funktionen. "Dass" verwendet man in einem Satz wie "Das war das letzte Mal, dass ich in einem Restaurant gegessen habe." Jedoch: "Das letzte Mal, als ich in einem Restaurant gegessen habe, war das Essen mittelmäßig."

Comment: @RHa Nicht unbedingt (vgl "Das letzte Mal, dass ich Seife gegessen habe, war ich vier") https://www.goettinger-tageblatt.de/Nachrichten/Kultur/Weltweit/Essen-unter-Menschen-II